# Unity increasing the scale of a GameObject not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

**GameObject:**

I have a gameObject "Sphere" with the following properties:

- Starting scale of 1.5 (x, y, z).
- A script that makes sure that the scale is between 0 and 150.

**What do I have:**

Now, I have implemented a function that the user can scale the GameObject by using the HTC Vive Controllers (we are using Virtual Reality).

This function checks the distance between the controllers (often between -1 and 1 to decide if we want to upscale or downscale the object).

So when I have this value between -1 and 1, I am scaling the GameObject by the value multiple the sensitivity (this is editable in the Unity Editor).

**What do I want:**

This works pretty fine, although, I want to increase the sensitivity over time on a not hard-coded way. So when the GameObject is very small, the scaling will be very slow. When the GameObject is pretty big, the scaling will go quick.

**What have I tried:**

I have this value (between -1 and 1), then I will multiply this value with the sensitivity.

Then I will multiply by the current scale / the maximum scale.

However, this is causing an issue that the zooming in is going faster then zooming out.

The code that I am using looks like below:

```
float currentControllerDistance = Vector3.Distance(LeftHand.transform.position, RightHand.transform.position);
float currentZoomAmount = currentControllerDistance - ControllersStartPostionDifference; // Value is between -1 and 1.

currentZoomAmount = currentZoomAmount * ScalingSensitivity; // Multiplying by the value in the Unity Editor.

float currentPercentage = ObjectToScale.transform.localScale.x / ObjectMaximumScale.x; // Current scale percentage in comparison to the maximum scale.

currentZoomAmount = currentZoomAmount * currentPercentage; // Changing the ObjectToScale by adding the currentZoomAmount.
ObjectToScale.transform.localScale = new Vector3(ObjectCurrentScale.x + currentZoomAmount, ObjectCurrentScale.y + currentZoomAmount, ObjectCurrentScale.z + currentZoomAmount);
```

Does someone have any idea how to do this kind of scaling?

Thanks in forward.

Comment: You'll need to show your code..

Comment: It's alot easier to understand what you're doing wrong if you show a sample of your code.

Comment: @BugFinder Added the code.

Comment: @Norse I added the code, hope it is clear enough, it is kinda complex.

Comment: like everything in unity, when it comes to smooth scaling it usually involves deltatime.. I used transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(currentsize, newsize, lerppos); and set lerppos to += 1* time.deltaTime; works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you're looking for way to specify the rate of change of your scaling so that it changes faster when closer to the maximum scale, which sounds like a job for an [easing function](https://easings.net/).

If your project already uses a tweening library like DOTween, this should be easily done with that library's capabilities. If not, you can try using the equation for the cubic bézier, which is one of the simpler curves:

[Cubic Bézier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPDHu.png)

This is simply `y = x^3`, so you can try `ObjectMaximumScale.x * currentPercentage * currentPercentage * currentPercentage` to get a value that goes from 0 to `ObjectMaximumScale.x` when fed a value between 0 and 1 respectively.